# JavaFX Custom Cell Renderer for TreeTableView

Tags: javafx, treetableview

I am trying to implement a TreeTableView in JavaFX, containing 'MyData' objects, and having two columns. First column should contain a string; this was easy:

```
column1.setCellValueFactory((TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<MyData, String> entry) 
-> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(entry.getValue().getValue().toString()));
```

For the second column, I need to use some more complex data within the MyData object, and I want to render basically a sequence of icons that depict that data. So, I tried to create a custom cell renderer:

```
MyCellRenderer extends TreeTableCell<MyData, MyData> {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(MyData item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (item == null || empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
            setText(null);
        } else {
            // building some ContentPane with an HBox of Images here..
            setGraphic(contentPane);
        }
    }
}
```

and then set the column CellFactory and CellValueFactory as follows:

```
column2.setCellValueFactory((TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<MyData, MyData> entry) 
-> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(entry));

column2.setCellFactory(param -> new MyCellRenderer());
```

But I get this exception at runtime:

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn$CellDataFeatures cannot be cast
>   to MyData

I am afraid I don't really understand the meaning of the different generic types for all these classes, and also I am not sure about the "ReadOnlyObjectWrapper". I just tried to copy/paste and tweak it from the setup of the first column.

I would be very thankful if someone could shine some light on me. Unfortunately the oracle docs about TreeTableView don't go into that much detail, they just show simple examples.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `entry`, which is of the type `TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<MyData, MyData>`, as the initial value to a new `ReadOnlyObjectWraper` - a raw type - which is expecting a type of `MyData` at runtime and not `TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<MyData, MyData>`. As you can see, there is a mismatch of generic types.

Try changing

```
new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(entry)
```

to

```
new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(entry.getValue().getValue())
```

The reason for two `getValue()` calls is because the first `entry.getValue()` returns a `TreeItem<MyData>` and the second `getValue()` returns the actual `MyData` instance.

This is all assuming that your table is declared `TreeTableView<MyData>` and your column is declared `TreeTableColumn<MyData, MyData>`.

---

**Edit**: Since you said you don't really understand all the generic signatures here's a brief explanation.

```
TreeTableView<S>
```

Here the `S` is the type of object the `TreeTableView` displays. AKA, the model class. An example would be a `Person` class which would make `S` a `Person`.

```
TreeTableColumn<S, T>
```

The `S` here is the same as the `S` in the `TreeTableView` that the column is destined to be a part of. The `T` is the type of object that a `TreeTableCell` in the column will be displaying. This is normally a value contained within a property of the type `S`. Such as a `StringProperty` for a name of a `Person` which would make `T` a `String`.

```
TreeTableCell<S, T>
```

The `S` and `T` will be the same as the `TreeTableColumn` which the cell will be a part of.

Now, for the value callback:

```
Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<S, T>, ObservableValue<T>>
```

Again, the `S` and `T` represent the same types of the `TreeTableColumn` for which the `Callback` will belong to. This `Callback` returns an `ObservableValue` that contains the type  `T` so that the `TreeTableCell` can observe the value for changes and update the UI accordingly. In your case, since the type you want to display is not held in a property you return a new `ReadOnlyObjectWrapper` to satisfy the API requirements. If I continue the name `StringProperty` example I gave above you could end up with something like:

```
TreeTableView<Person> table = ..;
TreeTableColumn<Person, String> column = ...;
column.setCellValueFactory(dataFeatures -> {
    // This could all be done in one line but I figured I'd
    // make it explicit to show all the types used.
    TreeItem<Person> item = dataFeatures.getValue();
    Person person = item.getValue();
    return person.nameProperty(); // returns StringProperty which is an
                                  // ObservableStringValue which in turn
                                  // is an ObservableValue<String>
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
column2.setCellValueFactory((TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<MyData, MyData> entry) 
    -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(entry.getValue().getValue()));
```

Note that if you don't use raw types (i.e. use `ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>` or `ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<MyData>`, instead of just `ReadOnlyObjectWrapper`), the compiler will inform you of the error, which is much better than trying to decipher what went wrong at runtime.

As you can see, the parameter type for the cell value factory is a `TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures` (see [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures.html)). This is simply a wrapper for the row value from which you're going to extract the data that are shown in the cell; this wrapper just contains the tree item for the row itself (which you get with `getValue()`), as well as the column to which the cell value factory is attached (`getTreeTableColumn()`) and the table to which that column belongs (`getTreeTableView()`).

The latter two, I believe,  are designed to enable you to write general, reusable, cell value factories, which you might want to customize on the basis of the column or table to which they're attached. (Use cases for this are hard for me to envisage, but nevertheless I suspect there is some occasion for them...)

The `TreeItem` containing the row (which you get with `entry.getValue()`), of course contains the row value itself (you get this with `getValue()`, which is why you end up with `entry.getValue().getValue()`), as well as other `TreeItem`-specific information (is it expanded, selected, etc etc).